# NullPointerException in Strings

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a question about `nullPointerException` in **Strings**. I have tried every possible solution I found but nothing worked. Here is the code:

```
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            final String type = dataSnapshot.child("status").child("userstate").getValue().toString();
            final String Date = dataSnapshot.child("status").child("date").getValue().toString();
            final String Time = dataSnapshot.child("status").child("time").getValue().toString();

            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            username.setText(user.getUsername());
            if(user != null) {
                    if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")) {
                        profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    } else {
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
                    }
            }

            readMessages(firebaseUser.getUid(), userid, user.getImageURL());

            if (type != null) {
                    if (type.equals("online")) {
                        userStatus.setText("online");
                    } else {
                        userStatus.setText("last seen: " + Time + " " + Date);
                    }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

And here is the **Logcat**:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.androidcoding.messenger.MessageActivity$3.onDataChange(MessageActivity.java:120)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Finally I used `type != null` but it still crashes the app. Where is the problem? I asked again something about *NullPointerException* but I can't understand how it can be solved in every  case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the issue is because you convert `null` to `String`.

Just remove `.toString()`

```
final String type = dataSnapshot.child("status").child("userstate").getValue();
```

now your type might be `null` so you can check it with `null`.

Comment: When I do it like this it underlines the code like it is an error

Comment: then you can get Object in place of String. then after converting your object to a string.

Comment: I guess you just need a cast. `final String type = (String) dataSnapshot.child("status").child("userstate").getValue();` for the squigglys to disappear.

Comment: @MehulKabaria If I understood well you mean to replace **String** to **Object** and inside the if I should convert the **Object** to **String**, right?

Comment: @Fildor this seem to be correct but it still crashes when the app runs

Comment: Is `getValue()` supposed to return a type "Object" or "String" ?

Answer (score 0):

If your nodes are referenced correctly try this:

```
final String type = dataSnapshot.child("status").child("userstate").getValue(String.class);
final String Date = dataSnapshot.child("status").child("date").getValue(String.class);
final String Time = dataSnapshot.child("status").child("time").getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: Hmmm I think this worked... Thank you all for your help!